# How to uninstall Python site-package which was installed using "python setup.py develop"?

Tags: python, uninstallation, pip, setup.py

pip freeze result show:

> -e git+git@github.com:Tallmad/zeus@6155c80f5b87cba0aeb8c1bfb6fc6b6dd86b0fa8#egg=zeus-dev

It fails:

> pip uninstall git+git@github.com:Tallmad/zeus@6155c80f5b87cba0aeb8c1bfb6fc6b6dd86b0fa8#egg

Comment: Delete your virtualenv and start over: `deactivate; rmvirtualenv <current-venv>; mkvirtualenv <current-venv>` If you are not using virtualenvwrapper, consider adding this to your stack now: http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: There are many other packages in my virtualenv. And I just want to uninstall my project while remain others

Comment: Try running the install again with --record to get a list of all the files it touches

Comment: Start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualenv+uninstall+git+package End up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926566/how-to-uninstall-a-git-repo-using-pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it. Two steps:

Step 1: I install my project 'zeus'

> python setup.py install

Setp 2: uninstall it:

> pip uninstall zeus

Done

Comment: I think you could've skipped Step 1.

Comment: I've tried skipping Step 1, but it didn't work. So Step 1 cannot be skipped

Answer (score 0):

1. install again with `--record` to store installing files.

   > python setup.py install --record install.log
2. manually remove those files from the record file

   > xargs rm -rf < install.log